# How to access nested object using this code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: link to the firebase screenshot]

My firebase structure which I cant change unfortunately has this additional level which is 0 for all items. I am trying to build a webpage where I am listing my database. If I remove (to test) the  level which is 0 for all the code works. However, the JSON file I am stuck with has this 0 level.

I am not sure how to adjust my code so that it will retrieve the name not from the first item underneath domain but "item underneath domain /0/"

Anyone any clue how to help a n00b out?

```
function FetchAllData() {
    firebase.database().ref('domain').once('value',function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach( 
            function(GrandChildSnapshot){
                let name = ChildSnapshot.val().Name;
                let roll = ChildSnapshot.val().Profile;
                let sec = ChildSnapshot.val().Type;
                let gen = ChildSnapshot.val().URL;

                addItemsToList(name,roll,sec,gen);
            }
            )
    });
}

window.onload(FetchAllData());
```

I tried to add a path into the variable but it did not retrieve correctly

Comment: It looks like an array, but you are trying to access properties like it would be an object. Try `ChildSnapshot.val()[0].Name`

Comment: thanks a ton that worked!! appreciate it

Comment: Or better yet, `const kids = ChildSnapshot.val(); const kid = kids[0];` then `let name = kid.Name;` Cache the result of calling the function.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Konrad. Or Heretic Monkey for that matter. :)